# OpenCV FlannBasedMatcher segmentation faults on knnMatch()

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV's FlannBasedMatcher in order to match keypoints between camera images coming from a Kinect and some sample images. I wrote the following method in order to process a `cv::Mat` image:

```
cv::SurfFeatureDetector feature_detector;
cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor descriptor_extractor;

// Contains all the information we need about an image
struct ImageInfo
{
  int                       width,
                            height;
  std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
  cv::Mat                   descriptors;
  cv::FlannBasedMatcher     matcher;
};

void ObjectRecognizer::getImageInfo(const cv::Mat& image, ImageInfo& image_info)
{
  image_info.width  = image.cols;
  image_info.height = image.rows;
  // Detect keypoints
  feature_detector.detect(image, image_info.keypoints);
  // Compute descriptors
  descriptor_extractor.compute(image, image_info.keypoints, image_info.descriptors);
  // Train matcher
  std::vector<cv::Mat> descriptor_vector;
  descriptor_vector.push_back(image_info.descriptors);
  image_info.matcher.add(descriptor_vector);
  image_info.matcher.train();
}
```

I call this method to get an `ImageInfo` struct from both my camera image and my sample image.

If i train the matcher with the descriptors from my camera image and call the method with the descriptors from my sample image, everything works fine (as in it not only runs, i am actually able to detect the sample image within the camera image):

```
cam_img_info.matcher.knnMatch(sample_info.descriptors, matches, 2);
```

If i do it the other way round and try using the matcher trained with the sample image descriptors, i get a segmentation fault:

```
sample_info.matcher.knnMatch(cam_img_info.descriptors, matches, 2);
```

It runs perfectly fine (but of course i am not able to detect any objects in my camera image) if i use an empty `cv::Mat` to match against the trained sample descriptors:

```
cv::Mat descs;
sample_info.matcher.knnMatch(descs, matches, 2);
```

Any ideas on what might be the problem?

Comment: I'm running to similar problems on iOS (SIGABRT) when using FlannBasedMatcher and knnMatch. It works, sometimes, but when I cover the camera, it SIGABRTs. Sometimes it says: OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (type=0
) in buildIndex_, file ../modules/flann/src/miniflann.cpp, line 315
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception ...... Other times it says: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((globalDescIdx>=0) && (globalDescIdx < size())) in getLocalIdx, file .../modules/features2d/src/matchers.cpp, line 163 ... Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: So I just tried one thing. Do knnMatch only if image_info.keypoints.size() > 0 ... it works! EDIT: only if knnMatch's last argument is 1. Don't know why.